# Connecting Azure DB from local is very slow

Tags: database, performance, azure, connection, azure-sql-database

We are using Azure Cloud for our web application.

Once we work outside of the office we want to connect Azure Sql Database.

But the connection is too slow. Sometimes it takes one minute to get a response.

Is there any settings we need to apply to increase connection speed?

Comment: Is there a big difference in network speed?As you know, Azure SQL Database is cloud database. Typically, the network environment affects the connection response.

Comment: please post your SQL Azure DB reservation size and anything you can about your network configuration.

Comment: DTU 50, Data Max Size: 250GB What is a reservation size?

Comment: It's the DTU 50 stuff.  You are using a Standard S2 database reservation size (resource reservation).  If you measure "select 1", that will give you the base round trip speed to and from Azure from your location to remove the cost of the query.  If the select 1 is slow, then it's the network speed (and your main option is a faster reservation size but it will only provide improvements to the limit of your network).  If it's the query itself that is slow, then keep in mind you may need to tune the query (indexes, etc) or consider a larger reservation size if it is bound on CPU or IO.